# Java Error: Core dumped failed! Try doing ulimit -c unlimited before you start java next time!

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to play Minecraft, more specifically Feed The Beast (A mod variation) and on attempting to load, it fails with the following:

```
Core dumped failed! Try doing ulimit -c unlimited before you start java next time!
```

It's very annoying when I don't remember to do this, then I have to wait a long time for it to load. Is there any way to permanently fix this Java error?

Answer (score 2):

Do what it says. In a terminal run, `ulimit -c unlimited` before you start playing.

From `man ulimit`:

```
User limits - limit the use of system-wide resources. A bash built-in command that provides control over the resources available to the shell and to processes started by it, on systems that allow such control

Syntax
      ulimit [-acdfHlmnpsStuv] [limit]

Options

   -c   The maximum size of core files created.
```

If you want a permanent solution, edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` and change the first line to:

```
#<domain> #<type> #<item> #<value>
*         soft    core    unlimited
```

Comment: My point is, sometimes I forget, then it takes a while to load, crashes, and then I have to load it again. I was wondering if there was something I could do that would fix it forever.

Comment: you could also try putting `ulimit -c unlimited` in your `~/.bashrc`